# Apache - Proxy different services via one server

Tags: apache, web-services, proxy

My goal is to access different webservices in my network via one proxy server. The background problem is that the proxy server is the only server that is accessible by the clients.

The proxy server has the IP 192.168.1.1 and I've got a webservice running on IP 192.168.1.124 (IPs and names are just examples).
When a client server accesses http://192.168.1.1/webservice/ his requests have to be forwarded to http://192.168.1.124/, but the client should never see the actual IP of the webservice. The browser of the client should still just see the URL http://192.168.1.1/webservice/*.
Additionaly the session of the client should still work via this proxy connection and if the webservice executes any redirects they have to be caught and attached to the proxy URL.
For example when the webservice redirects the first request to http://192.168.1.124/home.html the client should see http://192.168.1.1/webservice/home.html

I googled a lot, but I couldn't come up with a suiting solution.
The last configuration that I used is:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /snipeit/ http://192.168.1.124/
ProxyPassReverse /snipeit/ http://192.168.1.124/
```

With this configuration the requests get forwarded to the webservice in the way I want. But when the webservice replies with a different URL like http://192.168.1.124/home.html the client is redirected to http://192.168.1.1/home.html and the browser is showing a 404 error. Since it should go to http://192.168.1.1/webservice/home.html. When I type this URL manually I get the right page.

What am I doing wrong?/What did I miss?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO Andy! The behaviour you see is expected, please take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome :-)
Can you tell me how to get the client get to the URL http://192.168.1.1/webservice/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:
(first make sure `mod_proxy_html` is enabled)

```
<Location /app1/>
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app1/
</Location>
<Location /app2/>
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /app2/
</Location>
```